# why is hit() method appending all hands

Tags: python-3.x

[BlackjackDeck class](https://i.stack.imgur)

[players class, a BlackjackDeck sub class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG1f8.png).com/bIwv6.png

[an instance of Players class and use of hit() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpK1H.png)

working on a blackjack game using Python. My question is why, when testing of the hit() method, are all the players' hands appended instead of just 'Abi'?

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Also refer to the article- how to ask a good question on stackoverflow (google for it)

Comment: Thanks, Rafael. I will read the article and repost it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with how you create the hands.

```py
hand_holder = [[]] * 7
print(hand_holder)
hand_holder[0].append("test")
print(hand_holder)
```

This creates one list and copies it so you have 7 copies of the same 1 list. So changing 1 will change all of them since they are all the same list

**OUTPUT**

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['test'], ['test'], ['test'], ['test'], ['test'], ['test'], ['test']]
```

Instead you should create new list for each player so that updating one doesnt affect the others

```py
hand_holder = [[] for _ in range(7)]
print(hand_holder)
hand_holder[0].append("test")
print(hand_holder)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[['test'], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```